# how to style an activity in android

Tags: android, background, styles

I was surfing on the internet and by chance I got this image ..
http://blog.donnfelker.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/qonqr-example.png

So I tried to put a backgroung color to my activity but the problem is that the whole activity is being covered by that color ..  what to do if i don't want the colors to be applied on the `EditText` fields ...?

And please also tell how to get this `TextView` style as in the image written "Create an account" ?

P.S. I am a newbie .

Answer (score 0):

Try to split your activity into different layouts.and then apply background colors to those layouts.And for edittext you set its different background .

Comment: oh yes .. I changed the background color of `EditText` field ... It's fine ...  And plz tell me how to get that font ??

Comment: To change your default font you need to add .ttf font in assets folder of your project and then access the font using these in oncreate method of your activity..:-Tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);                         Typeface font1=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font1.ttf");
    
     Tv.setTypeface(font1);